# How to generate a random number (within # of digit constraint) VISUAL BASIC .net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write a random number generator that generates a number based on a user input (I know how to get and implement user input). Where I am struggling is it needs to be able to generate a number not between to values (eg. 1-20), but rather between a maximum number of digits (eg. Userinput= 3, rannum= 278 OR Userinput = 5, rannum = 84383).

Sorry if this is a stupid question, just cant find a way of doing this

Thank you for reading this and I look forward to your responses!

Comment: I'm not familiar with VB.NET, but something like `Int(Rnd()*10^Userinput))` should do the job, assuming `Userinput` holds a valid number.

Comment: If `N` is the number of digits, the number will be from `10^(N-1)` to `10^N - 1` inclusively, or from `10^(N-1)` to `10^N` [exclusively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.8#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_).

Comment: The number of digits *also* sets the minimum and maximum values.  Like 3 digits means [100..1000).  Use the ^ operator.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, I tired doing this: rannum = Int(Rnd() * 10 ^ Userinput) When I do this is creates some very weird and very predictable numbers (same one very time, but it does remain with in the number of digits)

Comment: Before calling Rnd, use the Randomize statement without an argument to initialize the random-number generator with a seed based on the system timer.

Comment: We are talking about VisualBasic.Net right? not VB6?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the randomizer before using the Rnd function.
Randomizer() is using the system time as a seed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.vbmath.randomize?view=netframework-4.8

If you don t use Randomizer to generate a seed the random numbers will be the same if you run it multiple times.
below an example on how to use the randomizer

```
        Randomize()

        Dim Userinput As Integer = 5

        Dim rannum As Integer = Int(Rnd() * 10 ^ Userinput)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you want to do like this:

```
            Public Class FormRandom
                Private Shared Rnd As New Random

                Private Sub FormRandom_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
                    Dim UserMax As Integer = 1000 'Get from user
                    Dim RandomNumber As Integer = Rnd.Next(1, UserMax)
                End Sub
            End Class
```

If you want declare Rnd local for some reason then you will want to create a seed:

```
            Public Class FormRandom
                Private Sub FormRandom_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
                    Dim Rnd As New Random(Now.Millisecond)
                    Dim UserMax As Integer = 1000 'Get from user
                    Dim RandomNumber As Integer = Rnd.Next(1, UserMax)
                End Sub
            End Class
```

Comment: From MS docs "Both to improve performance and to avoid inadvertently creating separate random number generators that generate identical numeric sequences, we recommend that you create one Random object to generate many random numbers over time, instead of creating new Random objects to generate one random number."

Comment: @Mary Are you suggesting there is something out of line with my example?

Comment: No. I was just expanding with the docs and reinforcing the idea that your first example is preferred. Sorry, I did not mean to contradict or correct.

Comment: Oh, ok. I figured that. Just wanted to make certain. No apology needed.

Answer (score 0):

I used the .Net Random class. The function will return a random number with N digits where N is the number of digits the user requests. To get a range starting with 0 and 1 to N digits just replace `CInt(10 ^ (UserInput - 1))` with `0`. The `.Next` method can take 2 parameters; the first is included as the lower limit and the second is one more than the upper limit.

```
Private Rand As New Random

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim input As Integer
    Dim MyRandom As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, input) AndAlso input > 0 AndAlso input < 11 Then
        MyRandom = GetRandomWith_N_Digits(input)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number between 1 and 11")
    End If
    MessageBox.Show(MyRandom.ToString)
End Sub

Private Function GetRandomWith_N_Digits(UserInput As Integer) As Integer
    Dim RandomInt As Integer
    If 10 ^ UserInput <= Integer.MaxValue Then
        RandomInt = Rand.Next(CInt(10 ^ (UserInput - 1)), CInt(10 ^ UserInput))
    Else
        RandomInt = Rand.Next(CInt(10 ^ (UserInput - 1)), Integer.MaxValue)
    End If
    Return RandomInt
End Function
```